# Count elements in div by one of classes

Tags: javascript

I have a div with a bunch of elements in it. Each element has multiple classes like `class="circle green"` or `class="square blue"` or `class="triangle red"`.Now I need to count element by one of those classes, like how many red elements are in the div. Or how many circles are places in the div. How do I do that?

Comment: With querySelectorAll.

Comment: my bad, my bad. I asked a wrong question. Too sleepy, sorry. I meant how do I find how many element of the same class are in the div? I want to know if I have two or more red elements in div. Not to check every possible color, just duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way could be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( 'square' ).length
```

In case of div you need to first select somehow div. Here is an example where div has an id 'myDiv'

```
document.getElementById( 'myDiv' ).getElementsByClassName( 'square' ).length
```

more info you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: I disagree with you. It returns amount of elements with given class. You can also apply `getElementsByClassName` to specific element in dom not only to document. So you narrow down your search

Comment: @lilezek why is this not a solution? op wants to count by "**one** of those classes", so `querySelectorAll` is not needed

Comment: I've update my comment to also contain solution for specific element not for entire document.